# Pyspark Dataframe Column Arithmatic Operations

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pysprak that has two columns, Flight Origin and Flight Destination.

| Origin | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| LAX | JFK |
| LHR | LAX |
| ATL | DFW |
| JFK | LHR |
| ATL | LHR |

What I want to do using Pyspark dataframes is to calculate how many times a single distinct value has appeared in both columns, for e.g  LHR has appeared 3 times in both columns.

Expected Output

| Airport | Count |
| --- | --- |
| LAX | 2 |
| ATL | 2 |
| LHR | 3 |
| JFK | 2 |
| DFW | 1 |

Is there any way I can count get a count for both columns?

I have used the Distinct filter using Pyspark DataFrames on single columns i.e. once on Origin and once on Destination and get a list for e.g.

Distinct count in Origin:
LAX-1
ATL-2
LHR-1
JFK-1
and
Distinct count in Destination:
LAX-1
DFW-1
LHR-2
JFK-1

Now how do I perform addition on these columns?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please show expected output

Comment: EXPECTED OUTPUT
LAX-2
ATL -2
LHR-3
JFK- 2 
DFW-1

Comment: then Srinivas solution should be good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df=spark.createDataFrame([('LAX','JFK'),
... ('ATL','DFW'),
... ('LHR','LAX'),
... ('JFK','LHR'),
... ('ATL','LHR')], schema=['origin','destination'])
>>> o_count=df.select(F.col('origin').alias('place'))
>>> d_count=df.select(F.col('destination').alias('place'))
>>> o_count.unionAll(d_count).groupBy('place').count().show()
+-----+-----+
|place|count|
+-----+-----+
|  LHR|    3|
|  DFW|    1|
|  ATL|    2|
|  LAX|    2|
|  JFK|    2|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. Your solution works.

Comment: Please could you accept the answer